How can I specify the data structure so requirements of mypy and pydantic are satisfied
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import List, Optional
from datetime import datetime

class Vault(BaseModel):
    VaultARN: str
    VaultName: str
    CreationDate: datetime
    LastInventoryDate: Optional[datetime] = None
    NumberOfArchives: int
    SizeInBytes: int

class VaultListResponse(BaseModel):
    VaultList: List[Vault]

# Example data
data = {
    "VaultList": [
        {
            "VaultARN": "arn:aws:glacier:eu-central-1:801680170242:vaults/ab_2017_bis_2022",
            "VaultName": "ab_2017_bis_2022",
            "CreationDate": "2022-07-05T08:37:25.552Z",
            "LastInventoryDate": "2024-09-14T18:54:58.863Z",
            "NumberOfArchives": 5712,
            "SizeInBytes": 28571666494
        },
        {
            "VaultARN": "arn:aws:glacier:eu-central-1:801680170242:vaults/photos-161218",
            "VaultName": "photos-161218",
            "CreationDate": "2016-12-18T15:03:19.426Z",
            "LastInventoryDate": "2024-09-14T18:54:52.853Z",
            "NumberOfArchives": 28418,
            "SizeInBytes": 94052378166
        }
    ]
}

# Pass the entire dictionary to the VaultListResponse constructor
vault_list_response = VaultListResponse(**data)
print(vault_list_response)

the code works but mypy give me an error which I canot get rid off: Argument 1 to "VaultListResponse" has incompatible type "**dict[str, list[dict[str, object]]]"; expected "list[Vault]"mypyarg-type
How can I specify the structure of data so it satisfies also mypy

I'd argue the typing isn't the problem, it's the lazy use of **data instead of just passing data["VaultList"] as the argument. Statically, the type checker doesn't know that data has exactly one key, or that that key is the keyword argument expected by VaultListResponse.

(But also, your data doesn't consist of VaultObjects, only dicts that can be used to create VaultObjects.)

Try
data = {
    "VaultList": [
        Vault(**{
            "VaultARN": "arn:aws:glacier:eu-central-1:801680170242:vaults/ab_2017_bis_2022",
            "VaultName": "ab_2017_bis_2022",
            "CreationDate": "2022-07-05T08:37:25.552Z",
            "LastInventoryDate": "2024-09-14T18:54:58.863Z",
            "NumberOfArchives": 5712,
            "SizeInBytes": 28571666494
        }),
        Vault(**{
            "VaultARN": "arn:aws:glacier:eu-central-1:801680170242:vaults/photos-161218",
            "VaultName": "photos-161218",
            "CreationDate": "2016-12-18T15:03:19.426Z",
            "LastInventoryDate": "2024-09-14T18:54:52.853Z",
            "NumberOfArchives": 28418,
            "SizeInBytes": 94052378166
        })
    ]
}

or
vault_list_response = VaultListResponse.model_validate(data)
print(vault_list_response)

With the second you'd simply lose the type checking on the arguments. But sometimes that's what you need. Don't know if thats your case though.

The first version did not work either. Second works. Thanks
